# Specific keys have inherently different behavior when used in the exact same way

Tags: javascript, input

I have this code that lets a rectangle move, crouch, and jump, but for some reason I can't jump if the crouch and movement keys are held down, if the jump key is 'w'. If the jump key is 'm' for example, the code works perfectly fine. There are other weird cases, for example, if the jump key is 'c', you can jump while crouching and moving to the left, but it doesn't work if you try to move to the right.

I tried removing the crouch and movement functions, and the problem still persists if you hold down the buttons. I have left them in to more closely resemble my target use case.

Here are all of the keys that have unexpected behavior, r means that you can't jump while crouched and moved to the right, l means you can't jump while crouched and moving to the left, and x means you can't jump while crouching and moving in both directions.

q: r,
w: x,
e: l,
u: x,
o: x,
p: x,
a: r,
s: x,
d: r,
z: r,
x: x,
c: l

The rest of the keys are fine and work as expected.
I only tested 'i' for player two, and it seems to half work for player two but fully work for player one which is confusing? I don't understand why the key I'm using for input affects whether I'm able to jump or not.

Here is my javascript code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")
const SPEED = 8
const GRAVITY = 1

canvas.width = 16 * 50
canvas.height = 9 * 50

const FLOOR = canvas.height - 30

jumpKey = 'w'

const keys = ['a', 's', 'd', 'j', 'k', 'l', jumpKey, 'i']

const pressed = {}
for (key of keys) {
    pressed[key] = false
}

const playerOneKeys = {
    up: jumpKey,
    left: 'a',
    down: 's',
    right: 'd',
}

const playerTwoKeys = {
    up: 'i',
    left: 'j',
    down: 'k',
    right: 'l',
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (keys.includes(event.key)) {
        pressed[event.key] = true
    }
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (keys.includes(event.key)) {
        pressed[event.key] = false
    }

})


class Player {
    constructor(keys, xValue) {
        this.width = 95
        this.height = 230

        this.position = {
            x: xValue,
            y: FLOOR - this.height
        }
        this.velocity = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }

        this.keys = keys

        this.lookingRight = true
    }

    move() {
        if (pressed[this.keys.right]) {
            this.velocity.x = SPEED
            this.lookingRight = true

        } else if (pressed[this.keys.left]) {
            this.velocity.x = - SPEED
            this.lookingRight = false

        } else {
            this.velocity.x = 0
        }

        this.position.x += this.velocity.x
    }

    crouch() {
        if (pressed[this.keys.down] && this.position.y == FLOOR - this.height) {
            this.height = 230 * 1 / 2
            this.width = 95 + 20
            this.position.y = FLOOR - this.height
        
        } else if (!pressed[this.keys.down] && this.height == 230 / 2) {
            this.height = 230
            this.width = 95
            this.position.y = FLOOR - this.height
        }
    }

    jump() {
        this.velocity.y += GRAVITY

        if (pressed[this.keys.up] && this.position.y == FLOOR - this.height) {
            this.velocity.y = -14
        }

        this.position.y += this.velocity.y
        if (this.position.y >= FLOOR - this.height) {
            this.velocity.y = 0
            this.position.y = FLOOR - this.height
            pressed[this.keys.up] = false
        }
    }

    update() {
        this.jump()
        this.move()
        this.crouch()
    }

    draw() {
        context.fillStyle = (this.lookingRight) ? '#CEFCBA' : '#747ddc'
        context.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height)
    }
}

const firstPlayer = new Player(playerOneKeys, 100)
const secondPlayer = new Player(playerTwoKeys, canvas.width - 100 - 95)

function clearScreen() {
    context.fillStyle = 'Black'
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}

function animation() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    clearScreen()
    firstPlayer.update()
    firstPlayer.draw()
    secondPlayer.update()
    secondPlayer.draw()
}

animation()
```

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: rgb(255,255,255)
        }

        canvas {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
    </style>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this may be due to the keyboard itself - some keyboards allow less simultaneously pressed keys than others

Comment: Good point, although 3 buttons as a limit seems a bit low.

Comment: @Hermanboxcar 3-key rollover is quite the standard for simple keyboards. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_rollover

Answer (score 1):

As Jaromanda mentionned in the comments, the problem is due to limited key rollover. Because it is expensive and mostly unnecessary to wire each key individually to a sensor, keys are linked together in sections, and powered in different sections. By detecting what sections are being powered, and what sections are letting power pass, the keyboard can detect keypresses without needing dozens of sensors.

Wikipedia has a nice piece on this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_rollover

The problem is when multiple keys in the same sections are pressed, as the sensors cannot determine which key is pressed. As such, the input is discarded.  WASD are so commonly used that they have more sensors attached to them, but IJKL does not. This is why IJKL fails when WASD succeeds, and also why seemingly random other keys work, as they are not all connected, meaning more sensors are used to read the spread out keys.

The solution is using keys that are farther apart, or keys that are better detected, such as the arrow keys:

```js
const playerTwoKeys = {
    up: 'ArrowUp',
    left: 'ArrowLeft',
    down: 'ArrowDown',
    right: 'ArrowRight',
}
```

Using the arrow keys and WASD, at least on my keyboard, fixes the problem of limited key rollover, allowing both rectangles to jump, crouch and move independently.

Modifier keys such as `Shift` and `Ctrl` also are typically sensed independently from the letter keys, although to use them, you'd need to turn off any special functionality they have in the browser page, which may or may not be ideal for your use case.

If your program is going to run on an older machine, or if you need consistency among many devices, it might be worth looking at ways to reduce the number of keypresses needed at once, such as using keys to toggle movement or crouching, rather than holding keys to maintain movement.